# Need help for hover over text effect in elementor pro

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, hover, elementor

I want to achive exactly like this website: https://www.petzl.com/INT/en

Like we will have 3 text/buttons by hovering will change background image, but only by hovering, but text should remain there not disappear by hovering over the text, also instantly when we release hover the main slider image should appear.

I have achieved the hovering but problem is I am unable to keep the text by hovering, also when image is changed it will not reset after hover to the main image I need.

Got the help of code from somewhere and used in elementor pro:

Below is the jquery code:

```js
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
var $ = jQuery
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-showme]').hover( function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        var showme = $(this).attr('data-showme')
        
        $('.all-img').hide()
        $('.all-text').show()
        $('all-text').hide()
        $('.' + showme).show()
        
    })
})
</script>
```

Below code for the compplete section having 3 images and 3 text:

```css
selector .all-img{
   display: none;
}
selector .img-1{
    display: block;
}
```

text classes are named as all-text text1.....and images as all-img img1....

Appreciate the help, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by only using CSS.

**Example**

```css
.box-image {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  background-color: #000;
  /* Original background */
  background-image: url(https://www.petzl.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/06868000007knNDAAY);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.box-image>div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.box-image>div img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

.box-image>div span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.box-image>div span:hover+img {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-image">
  <div class="sport">
    <span>Sport</span>
    <img src="https://www.petzl.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/0686800000D6sViAAJ"> </div>
  <div class="professional">
    <span>Professional</span>
    <img src="https://www.petzl.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/0686800000D6sSCAAZ"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Eduhud for your great solution, I want to have 3 texts that are in div to show in one row or one line in the center, can you please guide how to do that + how can I have multiple images like in the website of petzl.com they have multiple pics, like by hovering sometimes different images are appearing (can we do the images swap through css?)  link for website beta.edgerope.com.   Thanks alot

Comment: I want to achieve text on hover also, if somebody can help, please. I have added background video, also added links in the texts to go to another web if someone clicks on them. Thanks

Comment: Hi Samir, I answered and solved your original question. I would appreciate to upvote my answer and create a new question with the needs you have. I will be happy to help over there.

Comment: sure and thanks @Eduhud. I already created one and will create one more.